# Win2k8 Fileserver performance

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-server

This has happened a couple times - I have a virtualized win2k8 fileserver that slows to a crawl whenever someone copies a large amount of data to it(10gb+). Traversing the file tree as well as trying to read or write for other users also becomes painfully slow.

However, disk throughput, network usage, cpu, etc, seem to all be unsaturated. At the SAN / FC switch level things also appear to be fine. This seems to occur when someone uses windows explorer to copy files. When I transfer data through other means they go much faster.

Thank you in advance! Let me know if I missed any details.

Comment: Check your disk queue length and your paging activity (hard and soft page faults).  Perfmon or resource manager should let you do this... I suspect one of those is going to be your cause.

Comment: Your metrics - are you looking at them from a host perspective or a vmware perspective?